# Ionic 2 linked select option

Tags: angular, ionic2

In Ionic 2 how can I create linked select option.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option selected hidden>select country</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option selected hidden>select city</option>
    <option>Berlin</option>
    <option>Dortmund</option>
    <option>Hamburg</option>
    <option>Brussels</option>
</select>
```

And when I select Germany in select option two only shows german cities and when choose city they display data for that city

Comment: Please show us the code for your attempts to achieve this.

Comment: Is this your actual code, or do you have some data that you are iterating and populating these selects? If the latter, please show us a snippet of how your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dynamically populating the second `select` options. Have an object with all of the countries as the index to a list of the related cities and just attach an event listener to the change event on the county `select` which populates the cities `select` options:

```
{
    Germany: ['Berlin', 'Dortmund', 'Hamburg', 'Brussels', ...]
    Belgium: [...],
    England: [...],
}
```

Then you could even populate the county list using the indexes of the object and have the entire thing be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<select #countries ngModel>
    <option selected>select country</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option selected hidden>select city</option>
    <option *ngIf="countries.value == 'Germany'">Berlin</option>
    <option *ngIf="countries.value == 'Germany'">Dortmund</option>
    <option *ngIf="countries.value == 'Germany'">Hamburg</option>
    <option *ngIf="countries.value == 'Belgium'">Brussels</option>
</select>
```